# AngularJS: How to apply two filters conditionally?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two filters (buildFilter:searchText && filter:searchText) and I want to apply them conditionally when `searchText.APP.VERSION is true` apply `buildFilter:searchText` else `filter:searchText` I'm trying to use ternary operator but it's not working, not sure what are the different ways to achieve this.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="result in filtered = (vm.ProcessedResults | searchText.APP.VERSION ? buildFilter:searchText : filter:searchText) track by result.ENV_ID">
```

Kinda stuck on this, any help will helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<tbody ng-repeat="result in filtered | filter: (!searchText.APP.VERSION ? searchText:'') | buildFilter:(searchText.APP.VERSION ? searchText:'') track by result.ENV_ID">
```

this is an example of using multiple filters based on condition

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="mentor in mentors | filter:(search ? searchText:filterFn )">{{mentor}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

script

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MainCtrl( $scope ) {
    $scope.mentors = [ 'Jonathan', 'Nathan', 'Chris', 'Brian', 'Timothy' ];
    $scope.searchText = "j";
  $scope.search = false;

$scope.filterFn = function(car)
{
    // Do some tests

    if(car == 'Nathan')
    {
        return true; // this will be listed in the results
    }

    return false; // otherwise it won't be within the results
    };

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9gp3w7vx/